# How do you access models from other installed apps in Django when in the same subdirectory?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following structure for my project:

```
myproject/
|-- myproject/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- apps/
|   |-- dashboard/
|   |    |-- static/
|   |    |-- templates/
|   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |-- admin.py
|   |    |-- apps.py
|   |    |-- forms.py
|   |    |-- models.py
|   |    |-- tests.py
|   |    |-- views.py
|   |-- data/
|   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |-- apps.py
|   |    |-- models.py
|   |    |-- router.py
|   |    |-- tests.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
```

The settings file has these installed apps added:

```
'apps.data',
'apps.dashboard',
```

In the main project I can import from the apps I've created no issues. However, the dashboard app is dependant on the data app and I can't seem to import from the data app.

urls.py imports 'import apps.dashboard.views' with no issues but I've tried a number of things to import the models from data into dashboard. I'm using the models from data in the dashboard views.

None of the following work:

```
from data.models import ModelName
from apps.data.models import ModelName
from .data.models import ModelName
from .apps.data.models import ModelName
```

I get 'ImportError: No module named data.models' regardless.

In the apps.py files the DataConfig class has the names set to 'dashboard' and 'data'.

Can anyone explain how I can access the models from data in dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from .data.models` is an import *relative* to the current directory where that file exists, e.g., it would be looking for a `data` module directory inside your `dashboard` directory. If you want to refer to the `data` module relative to your `dashboard` module you should be able to use

```
from ..data.models import Foo
```

Using absolute imports depends on your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. You can play around with it by adjusting `sys.path` in a Python REPL.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I can advise a few things:

1. Check your `__init__.py` files if they are not empty you'll have
   access to only whats imported in them.
2. Check if you are not running into circular imports - if in `dashboard.models` you import from `data.models` when it imports from `dashboard.models`.
3. `from apps.data import models` or `from apps.data.models import ModelName` seems the right way to go - knowing this look for solutions.